# How Can I Solve Error : Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<table c'

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

When I Run This Code Show This Error Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'

data : https://github.com/DevangBaroliya/DataSet/blob/master/DistrictWiseReport20200607.xlsx

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = pd.read_excel('DistrictWiseReport.xlsx')
    data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the data from your github, right-click cell A1 in Excel and paste special as Unicode Text and save it as an .xlsx file, you will be able to read it in. I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do and what exactly is going wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your data file is not an Excel sheet, but an HTML table. `pandas.read_html()` might be able to handle it.